# Fold: foldtext() for each filetype

Tags: folding

1. how to have foldtext() for each filetype, because each filetype has a different kind of fold so multiple foldtext() in `vimrc` and enable for each filetype.
2. I'm thinking about multiple foldtext() functions in `vimrc` and enable that `customfunc()` to foldtext() via `local` of `au` command for `that` filetype. Is it possible and how would be an elegant way to achieve this?

EDIT: from @D.BenKnobl comment, I make it more visual, I'm not good with VimL and still the examples are pretty clear, I still need some clarification, so I'll add what I think and do here:

vim files in `/after/ftplugin` will alter the default behavior of vim filetype or append function. Because I don't see the calling of function in `folding.vim`, I understand that `vim` will automatically recognize that `folding.vim` contains all things for foldtext() or the whole file is foldtext() function and will be overwritten or alter the default foldtext() function for that filetype.

In `vim/after/ftplugin/markdown/folding.vim` I see `MarkdownFoldText` function that make firm about above conclusion. Basically `setlocal foldtext()`, define `MyMarkdownFoldFtpluginUndo` and `let b:undo_ftplugin` once leave that filetype with set local foldtext to `<`. Do I understand that correct?

So as my understanding, I should put foldtext() in `vim/after/ftplugin/rust.vim` like below:

```
if exists('b:undo_ftplugin')
  let b:undo_ftplugin .= ' | '
else
  let b:undo_ftplugin = ''
endif

" This is where my local foldtext() function for rust.vim
foldtext() <...>

if !exists("*MyRustFtpluginUndo")
  function MyCFtpluginUndo()
    setlocal tags<
    setlocal path<
    silent! nunmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>tr
  endfunction
endif

let b:undo_ftplugin .= 'call MyRustFtpluginUndo()'
```

Comment: Suggestion for answerers and OP: use filetype plugin structure for setting filetype-based things.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Does that mean when I leave that filetype, foldtext will be reset to default with filetype that not specify the foldtext() in their filetype plugin?

Comment: You can ensure that by setting `b:undo_ftplugin` properly. I use a sort of template for that; you can find examples [in my dotfiles](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/tree/master/links/vim/after/ftplugin)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Thanks, I've just added to 1st post. Can you help me to review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Example

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/rust.vim
if exists('b:undo_ftplugin')
  let b:undo_ftplugin .= ' | '
else
  let b:undo_ftplugin = ''
endif

function! RustFoldText()
  " cf. :help fold-foldtext
  return "text to display for foldtext"
endfunction

setlocal foldtext=RustFoldText()

if !exists("*MyRustFtpluginUndo")
  function MyRustFtpluginUndo()
    " reset options, undefine functions/commands, etc
    setlocal foldtext<
  endfunction
endif

let b:undo_ftplugin .= 'call MyRustFtpluginUndo()'
```

### Explanation of example

First, the file: `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` can contain custom vimscript to execute for filetypes. cf. `:help ftplugin`, `:help after`

The `b:undo_ftplugin` boilerplate is responsible coding; it ensures that, when switching filetypes (such as editing a new buffer), `vim` restores changed options to sensible values. You can also use it to clean up cruft (like removing mappings). cf. `:help b:undo_ftplugin`.

The meat is of course the function `RustFoldText`, which the option `'foldtext'` takes on locally. I've never written a foldtext function, but the vim help doc I reference above has good information on how to. So does this site, probably. It *must* return the text for the fold, and can make use of some magic variables to assist with that. cf. `:help fold-foldtext`, `:help setlocal`

---

**Notes**

I'm not sure if `foldtext` will allow `s:` script-local functions or not; you could experiment with that by using `function! s:RustFoldText()` and `setlocal foldtext=<SID>RustFoldText()`.

Comment: foldtext() must be global, just enable fold in `vimrc` locally for rust filetype. Thanks,  the question's answered, but I have another, how to persist `hi` for fold of each filetype, I find that each fold needs different highlight style for it. I'll open another question.

Comment: foldtext is a local option in vim, so not sure what you mean by must be global (windows for which it is not globally set retain the default). Do ask another question for your second one.

Comment: I see, so each object in vim is local meaning we can use `setlocal` to map it to a local variable? I `setlocal foldtext=RustFoldText()` and it only works this way, plus `s:RustFoldText()` in define the function and `setlocal` make `RustFoldText` isn't applied.

Comment: I’m not sure i quite follow what youre saying... take a look at the help in vim and see if you can answer your questions