# Fold: Different highlight style for fold of each filetype

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, folding

Extend of this question of fold: [Fold: foldtext() for each filetype](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/17823/14274)

We have fold for each filetype now but each fold need different highlight style of color, because `highlight` is global I tried to set it in `after/ftplugin/rust/folding.vim` and then reset it back to my favor default one but it doesn't effect.

Inconsistent behavior like if vim enter buffer of rust it set to new `hi` and then if leave `rust` buffer file it still persist the rust's `hi` for other buffers, that is not expected, leave `rust` buffer should set `hi` back to default and other buffers should take the default one instead of the new rust `hi`.

Like below:

```
if exists('b:undo_ftplugin')
  let b:undo_ftplugin .= ' | '
else
  let b:undo_ftplugin = ''
endif

" set highlight here for this specific fold
hi Fold ctermfg=10 ctermbg=12

" This is where my local foldtext() function for rust.vim
foldtext() <...>

if !exists("*MyRustFtpluginUndo")
  function MyCFtpluginUndo()
    setlocal tags<
    setlocal path<
    silent! nunmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>tr

    " set highlight back to default one
    hi Fold ctermfg=5 ctermbg=6
  endfunction
endif

let b:undo_ftplugin .= 'call MyRustFtpluginUndo()'
```

Note about: `hi Fold ctermfg=10 ctermbg=12` and `hi Fold ctermfg=5 ctermbg=6`

Answer (score 0):

Solution: we just need to set this `hi Fold ctermfg=10 ctermbg=12` in each fold file of each filetype, because of this set global, make sure to set to your favor hi of `Folded`, if not set, `Folded` of previous `folding` will take place.